# Polymer: OnClick inner component

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

I have the following structure, the thing is that when the object is wrapped it doesn't catch the click event.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="sentiment-bar.html">

<!--
A widget bar
-->
<polymer-element name="bar-component">
  <template>
  <style>
  :host {
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  </style>
  <div horizontal layout end id="sentimentBar">
    <sentiment-bar value="25" sentiment="very-negative" on-click="{{clickHandler}}"></sentiment-bar>
    <sentiment-bar value="15" sentiment="negative"></sentiment-bar>
    <sentiment-bar value="25" sentiment="neutral"></sentiment-bar>
    <sentiment-bar value="20" sentiment="positive"></sentiment-bar>
    <sentiment-bar value="15" sentiment="very-positive"></sentiment-bar>
    <paper-item label="Help"></paper-item>
  </span>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
Polymer('card-widget-sentiment', {
  clickHandler: function(){
      console.log(this);
  }
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

The paper-item works as expected, on the other hand, the sentiment-bar component with the click event is not working at all. However, if the sentiment-bar component is called outside the "bar-component" it works as expected. Maybe a shadow DOM event feature that I am not understanding well.

[image: on-click event not responding]

Comment: It might be easier to see some more of your code. Here's a jsbin that works ok: http://jsbin.com/pepaxi/3/edit  Click on 'x-baz' to see the alert.

Comment: well, I have updated the question, I think this is something around shadow DOM that I am not catching yet. I have read http://goo.gl/XfnL3 still not getting the event part.

Comment: The first parameter of the call to `Polymer()` doesn't match the element name `bar-component`. How do you get anything displayed at all?

Comment: @DirkGrappendorf That was my mistake. Turns out that shadow dom wasn't the problem, the problem was that another div was having a weird behaviour with the CSS. Thanks to robdodson, his example helped me to understand many things.